# threaded serial port communication in C++ with Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, serial-port, qthread

I am writing an QT desktop application that is going to display information received from a serial port. Therefore a class was created and packed into an DLL using standard Windows API features to communicate with the connected device (CreateFile, ReadFile, WriteFile, ...).

At the moment a timer calls the DLL at a predefined rate [< 200ms] and this leads the gui to freeze for short periods. Because of that i am thinking of using a thread to do the serial port stuff, that is also going to display everything.

Is is better to use threads for this problem or should i rewrite the class to do the work event based? The target is, that the gui doesnt freeze.

Edit:
I solved the problem using a QThread derived worker class with an overshadowed run() function, that handles the serial port communication in the background and updates the gui as new informations are available.

Comment: Is there any reason for not using [`QSerialPort`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#details)?

Comment: `QSerialPort` already does the job of communicating with a serial port asynchronously. Using threads for such a task will work if your aim is just not to freeze the GUI, but it is an overkill. The asynchronous approach works better with Qt, and it is far more maintainable.

Comment: When the project was started, we were not going to use qt. So we started by using only the windows api

Comment: Whatever the reason is. Since you've switched to using Qt now, I strongly recommend you to use QSerialPort` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice in many use cases to do all blocking (synchronous) I/O on a separate thread, especially when a graphical user interface is involved. [Here's a page I've referenced](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/12/13/io-threads-explained/) regarding the challenges with synchronous I/O (as opposed to asynchronous where your code doesn't block but is still single-threaded, or parallel as you're discussing). There are more issues than just what you brought up, for example:

- What if there is no data available? Does the GUI block until there is data? For example, if the sender was off then there would be no data
- What does the program do if the I/O device is no longer available? For example, if it is a USB-to-serial adapter, what happens if the adapter is unplugged?

Comment: Thanks for the article. it was very helpful. I will try std::thread to solve the problem. If the data is not aviable, the dll returns an error and it is logged in the gui. If it is unplugged, there will also be an error message displayed. I took care of those possibilities before that ;-)

Comment: As other commenters suggested: there are standard ways to do this in QT, you should consider their approaches. The link just discusses the paradigms. Unless you're just trying to learn threading for the fun of it.